# Battle of the Titans

Tags: discussion

I usually read textbooks about LaTeX and derivatives and I am always fascinated at how the experts manage to develop their code and get their desired output. In this website there are many topics floating around and with many of you gurus helping, it facilitates our learning. I was then wondering, why isn't there a show off per tag of the best of best LaTeX programmers. I know something like this has been done but not to the extent as per tag.

For example, there are tags like [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables), [amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amsmath), etc. Why cannot there be a show off of the many capabilities of TikZ, about constructs of professional tables or different designed tables that one can come up with. If there is a prize let there be one and if it is just to show off your talents let it be. I mean there was post recently about a [candle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43789/10898).

From my point of view that is a fabulous outcome. So what say you.

Comment: There is already a TikZ showcase at [TeXample](http://http://www.texample.net/).

Answer (score 9):

- A tag wiki page can be used to collect a list of important questions and answers.
- If you look for great questions regarding a topic, just filter by the tag and sort by votes. I wish, we could select a tag and see a list of answers sorted by votes. This is at least possible with the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).
- Regarding answers, you could use the badges to look-up great and famous answers, such as

  - [Great answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/25/great-answer)
  - [Guru answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/18/guru)
  - [Good answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/24/good-answer)
  - [Reversals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/55/reversal)
  - [Populists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/39/populist)

  Also here, I see it would be great if there would be a sort feature, it's just chronologically sorted, which is not the way I expect content to be sorted here.

Meta tags such as [great-contributions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/great-contributions) are not desired, furthermore we can only tag questions, not answers.

- Contest questions on the site are a great way to show talents:

  - [Contest: Show Off Your Skillz in TeX & Friends [TeX.sx birthday]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34482/contest-show-off-your-skillz-in-tex-friends-tex-sx-birthday)
- [Our blog](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/) is another place for pointing to great contributions on the site
- Another thought: we could extend the [TeXample.net](http://texample.net/) showcase site by a LaTeX gallery, starting for example with the great contributions to the contest question, each linked to the original TeX.SX place. Also such is meant by my [cooperation suggestion](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2236/cooperation-of-tex-stack-exchange-and-texample-net).

Comment: Perhaps add a reference to the first birthday "skillz" contents: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34482/contest-show-off-your-skillz-in-tex-friends-tex-sx-birthday

Comment: The reference above is what I cited as a topic I had read about showing off your skills. I am amazed at the work you do here, Stefan and I am contemplating on purchasing your book. But I imagine your work is not even half of what you know. I would be very interested in seeing what levels of complexity and capabilities latex can take you to and how topics like tikz, pstricks, tables, formatting and stuff like that can be tackled by experts(you guys here) and their magnificent output.

Comment: @Werner: thanks, added